# How to specify filepath for KDB tickerplant to save data to at End of Day

Tags: kdb

I'm wondering how to specify a filepath for my tick setup to save to when `.u.endofday` is sent from the tickerplant. Currently, when this message is sent the RDB is saved to the working directory where the `tick.q` file is.

Is there away to pass in a file path so that it is saved to `../../HDB` rather than `../../Tick`?

Answer (score 2):

In the vanilla r.q script, the tables are saved down using

`` .Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym] ``

where the second parameter is the directory that the tables are saved to.

`:.

represents the current directory. You can change it to something else, for example `:/home/data/hdb

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qhdpf-save-tables

If you are using the plain r.q script, referring to 
https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/r.q

There is a comment under .u.rep, suggesting to modify the 'system cd' command, where you can specify any directory you like. This will change the directory inside the r.q process. Then when .Q.hdpf is called it will save the tables to that directory. The rdb calls .u.rep on start up.

```
.u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;if[null first y;:()];-11!y;system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y};    
/ HARDCODE \cd if other than logdir/db
```

You could have

```
system "cd /home/data/hdb"
```

which will change the current directory to this location

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup there is couple of ways to do this.

But I think the most efficient would be for you to look at the .u.end function that is called in you RDB and see what save down function is used there.

Search the place where .u.end is defined on the RDB and look at the save_down functions. 
Look for .Q.dpft which is most likely or there is set command.
Documentation on the .Q.dpft:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdpft-save-table

Where the first argument that is fed in is the directory path. 
So could add a directory there in the form of

```
hsym `$"/path/path/HDB"
```

Which returns

```
`:/path/path/HDB
```

as a symbol to be inserted to the function.

There might be different ways of tables being saved down, but that is most likely way it is done.

There is also different ways to choose a directory with par.txt file that is loaded in. So useful to see if par.txt file is loaded in with the .Q.par function called on the RDB.

```
 .Q.par[`:.;.z.d;`]
```

if the answer is just:

```
 `:./2020.05.09/
```

That means it is using the directory you launched the script in.

Here you can find some more documentation on this:
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/partition/

Comment: Yes .Q.hdpf (which calls .Q.dpft) is defined in my rdb.q file in .u.end as 

`.Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym]`

However when I modify then to 

`.Q.hdpf[hsym `$"../../HDB",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym]`

It still saves the data down to the directory in which the script was launched from

https://code.kx.com/q/wp/rt-tick/#uend